# Serialize SqlAlchemy query across process boundary

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

Using `Python==3.10.12` and `sqlalchemy==2.0.23` (and postgres 12 under Ubuntu, if that makes any difference):

**How do I serialize an existing SqlAlchemy query so I can deserialize it and fetch its results in another process?**

In other words, I have a SqlAlchemy `query` in process=1, but want to run `for result in query.yield_per(1000): …` and `query.count()` in process=2.

I'm not looking to serialize the query results. I'm looking to serialize & deserialize the query itself.

It is essential the result set is never buffered/materialized at any point, because it's too large for RAM.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why you want to pass the query between the processes.  What are you trying to accomplish?  Can't you just pass the data to build the query to the other process and have it build the query there?

Comment: @IanWilson correct, I cannot. Building the query must happen in process=1.

Comment: Why can't you just pass batches of ids to the child processes?

Comment: Thanks but passing batches of IDs from process=1 to process=2 via some (presumably) back-and-forth IPC mechanism sounds both inefficient (extracting unneeded IDs in process=1, then loading back full objects from IDs in process=2) as well as monumentally complicated. I'd prefer to simply fetch what I need in process=2.

Comment: Btw process=2 doesn't even have the necessary libraries/dependencies to build the query, that's why `query` must be built in process=1. But the resulting query can be executed in process=2 no problem, it's just SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Usually people would want to split out sets of results into child processes and act on those results.  Either by passing on offset/limit windows or batches of result ids.  I guess I don't understand the use-case.  You can try this old serializer but I think the whole concept is going to be difficult to maintain and debug, ie. Pickling and unpickling sqlalchemy table objects and all the associated machinery.

[Deprecated Extension](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/serializer.html)

[discussion about future of extension](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5644)

Answer (score 0):

#### In process=1

```py
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql

# Serialize.
query_sql = str(query.statement.compile(dialect=postgresql.dialect(), compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True}))
```

#### In process=2

```py
from sqlalchemy import text, select

# Deserialize.
# We use `from_statement` to yield full ORM objects, rather than
# just Row tuples via `session.execute(text(query_sql))`.
objects = session.execute(
    select(MyTable).execution_options(yield_per=100).from_statement(text(query_sql)),
    execution_options={'yield_per': 100},
).scalars()

# Server-side cursor over the (large) query results.
for obj in objects.yield_per(100):
    …
```

This solution is not 100% because `objects` is of type `sqlalchemy.engine.result.ScalarResult` which has no `objects.count()` like the original `query.count()` does. There's no `objects.rowcount` either. How do I get the result count out efficiently (server-side query)?

One option is fetching the result count in process=1 and passing it to process=2 as an `int`, alongside the `query_sql` string. But that creates a race condition (count vs query out of sync), so I'd prefer to fetch them both in the same session.

Comment: I *think* `yield_per` used this way is actually getting all the results at once.  You need to pass it as execution options.  That is why rowcount is right though.

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/select.html#getting-orm-results-from-textual-statements

Comment: Fabulous! I confirm `from_statement()`  works, I updated my answer above @IanWilson. I'll check re. `yield_per` efficiency – documentation says it's server-side & unbuffered for postgres, but I do find it weird that `rowcount` worked like that.

Comment: I think you are using [Result.yield_per](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Result.yield_per) instead of [sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.execution_options.params.yield_per](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.execution_options.params.yield_per)

Comment: I find the SqlAlchemy documentation on `yield_per` thoroughly confusing. There are so many places to specify `yield_per`, with unclear precedence/semantics. I updated my answer with a couple of them, to make doubly-sure.

Comment: RSS RAM of the Postgres process keeps indeed growing and growing for large result sets. It never stops. Even with the triple `yield_per=100` above :( Python's (ORM) RAM is constant though.